# How to sync the rate of communication between socket server and client in linux

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, network-programming, ipc

I'm currently working on Linux Network programming and i'm new to this. I am developing some **Stream Socket (TCP)** based client-server applications in Linux Network Programming (C language).

**Server**- will continuously send the data 
**Client**- will continuously receive the data 
(both are running in while(1) loop)

- If **Server.c** is running on system-A and client.c is running on
  system-B. Server is sending some **100 packets/sec.** But due to some
  network issues the **Client** is able to receive **10 packets/sec.**
  i.e; Producer is producing more than the capacity of receiver.
- Is there any packet loss? or all packets will be transmitted as it is a TCP connection (reliable)?
- If any packet loss is there how to enable the retransmission?
- Any Flags or Options
- Is there any mechanism or procedure to handle producer-consumer problem?
- How Send() and recv() function works? (any blocking kind is there)

**Some help is needed!**
Please.

Thanking You all

Answer (score 1):

TCP has built-in flow-control.  You do not have to make any special arrangements at application level.  If the sender consistently tx's more data than the receiver can eat, the TCP stack will reduce the window size to reduce the transfer rate.  The effect is that the send() calls block for longer.

Comment: What about packet loss?
How to handle it? and retransmit them?

Comment: TCP takes care of that for you.